# How to refresh jsf page after pagination

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have created selectALL checkbox functionality in jsf + icefaces.  and i have implemented functionality like when i check selectAll checkbox it is selecting all the checkboxes across all the pages. but when i do pagination and if i do checked/unchecked select all checkbox then its works for only that page not acorss all the pages. i mean the state of row checkboxes is not consistent. i tried phaseListener for solving this but no luck.. can anyone suggest me the solution..

my code : jsf

```
<ace:column id="checkBox">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputLabel>
                                        <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAllID"
                                            value="#{shipBean.checkAll}"
                                            valueChangeListener="#{shipBean.getCheck}"
                                            partialSubmit="true" />
                                    </h:outputLabel>
                                </f:facet>
                                <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectOne"
                                    value="#{freight.checkBox}">
```

java:

```
    if (shipTrackingData != null) {

                if (shipTrackingData.getCheckAll()) {

                    for (ShipTrackBean check : shipTrackingData
                            .getShipTrackList()) {
                        check.setCheckBox(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    for (ShipTrackBean check : shipTrackingData
                            .getShipTrackList()) {

                        check.setCheckBox(false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks...

Comment: what is the scope of Managed Bean. I think you should be getting values of check box consistent in java code but they may not be getting reflected on UI. If you can have ajax functionality on when you go to previous or next page, and if you can render values by reading from bean which should have consistent values it may work.

Comment: @Manish thanks for the reply.. it is session scoped manged bean also i tried with viewscoped as well..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code for a JSF application, I have three pages:

index_1.xhtml
index_2.xhtml
index_3.xhtml

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class pross {
    private boolean challval=false;
    private boolean chval1=false;
    private boolean chval2=false;
    private boolean chval3=false;
.. getters and setters....
}
```

In each page I created two checkboxes one of them is to be selected across all pages if selected in any of them, but that checkbox is related to the same value (challval) for all pages.
there is also another checkbox for the page itself, one for each (chval1,chval2,chval3).

To test this I wrote this xhtml code for every page but you need to change the values according to each page, here is the code for index_1.xhtml, you need to change "go to" links to be able to access other pages:

```
 <h:body>
        <h:form>
        Hello, Test checkboxes:
        <br />
        Select this page: <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pross.chval1}" >
            <f:ajax render="outthis outall"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        This page select: <h:outputText id="outthis" value="#{pross.chval1}"/>
        <br/>
        Select all pages: <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pross.challval}">
            <f:ajax render="outthis outall"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        all pages select: <h:outputText id="outall" value="#{pross.challval}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:link outcome="index_2" value="Go to page 2" />
        <br/>
        <h:link outcome="index_3" value="Go to page 3" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

I see no problem here, and when I check "select all" in one page, it is still checked in the others, I think the idea is to connect the "select all" checkbox with same bean value for all pages.
Hope this is useful, thanks.

Comment: @Tiyab Thanks for the reply.. but i am using a datatable with pagination with single xhtml page. and here what happens when u do pagination select all functionality get failed .. you are right the it should take a same bean value..